# How to type GraphQL schema to specific numbers?

Tags: typescript, graphql, apollo-server

I have a function that the `interval` argument only accepts some specific numbers:

```
export interface ICandlesQuery {
  interval:
    | 60
    | 180
    | 300
    | 900
    | 1800
    | 3600
    | 7200
    | 14400
    | 21600
    | 43200
    | 86400
    | 259200;
}
```

I receive this number by parameter in my GraphQL Query:

```
const Query = gql`
  type Query {
    candleOHLC(interval: Int!): [Candles!]!
  }
`;

const resolvers: Resolvers = {
  Query: {
    candleOHLC: async (parent, { interval }) => getCandles({ interval }),
  },
};
```

However this is causing an error, because `interval` must not receive `Int`, but only the numbers defined in my interface.

Is it possible to create a custom Scalar to only accepts these numbers?

Thanks in advance